# React Native - hide components on swipe

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I have a layout where you can swipe horizontally using React Navigation 5's createMaterialTopTabNavigator or use a button on the bottom to transition between screens. The button appears on every screen and I would like to hide it during the swiping motion, and have it reappear when swiping stops.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
const Introduction1 = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ ...globalStyles.hTitle, ...globalStyles.h1 }}>Welcome</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.text}>
                Before you start there is a short introduction available.
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ ...globalStyles.text, ...globalStyles.bold }}>Do you want to see it?</Text>

            <BottomButtons name="Continue" destination="Introduction2" />
        </View>
    );
```

```
function SwiperNav() {
    return (
        <Swipe.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                style: {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            }}>
            <Swipe.Screen name="Introduction1" component={Introduction1} />
            <Swipe.Screen name="Introduction2" component={Introduction2} />
            <Swipe.Screen name="Introduction3" component={Introduction3} />
            <Swipe.Screen name="Introduction4" component={Introduction4} />
            <Swipe.Screen name="Introduction5" component={Introduction5} />
        </Swipe.Navigator>
    );
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you have a single button that switches between screens? Where is this button located and can you add some code? Also why do you need the bottom button if you have the top tab navigator?

Comment: I'm only using the top tab navigation for the swipe feature, although I could use a scrollview instead. The button is placed at the bottom and is swiped along with the page which I do not want.

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.continueBtn} onPress={() => navigation.jumpTo(destination)} >
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>{name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: You can edit your original post and put your code there. I recommend showing more than just the button itself. Also show your navigator. It would also help if you added a picture of your current layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original answer

I recommend a different approach. Hiding elements on swipe is difficult (in my own experience) and is not recommended according to the react navigation documentation:

> Some tab navigators such as bottom tab navigator also have a
> tabBarVisible option which can be used to hide the tab bar based on
> instructions in the Screen options resolution guide. However, we don't
> recommend using it since showing/hiding the tab bar mid-navigation can
> affect the animation of the stack navigator causing glitchy behaviour.

My approach is to define your continue button outside of your navigator.

First create a `RootNavigation` file at your directory root that looks like this.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function getCurrentRouteName() {
  return navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute().name;
}

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

The idea of this `RootNavigation` file is to get access to the `navigation` prop and get the current route name from inside our button. This is otherwise not possible if the button is placed outside of a navigator.

Pass the navigationRef to your `NavigationContainer`.

```
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';
// ...
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef}>
      <SwiperNav />
      <BottomButtons name="Continue" />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The following function is used to determine the next route the continue button should go to based on the current route name. If you want you can
clean up the code by using `constants` or `enums` for the route names.

```
const getSwipeNavigatorNextDestination = currentRouteName => {
  switch (currentRouteName) {
    case 'Introduction1':
      return 'Introduction2';
      break;
    case 'Introduction2':
      return 'Introduction3';
      break;
    // etc...
  }
};
```

I don't know what your `BottomButtons` component looks like exactly, but
the important thing is that you define a function that handles `onPress` where you
retrieve the next destination and navigate to that destination using `RootNavigation`.

```
const BottomButtons = ({name}) => {
  const handleBtnNavigate = () => {
    const nextDestination = getSwipeNavigatorNextDestination(
      RootNavigation.getCurrentRouteName(),
    );
    RootNavigation.navigate(nextDestination)
  };
  return <Button title={name} onPress={() => handleBtnNavigate()} />;
};
```

If you want to read more about the RootNavigation idea you can refer to the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/.

If there is anything unclear you can comment and I can clarify.

## Extension to the original answer

You should use only one NavigationContainer in your app. If you want to hide the continue button after navigating to a screen that is not part of the introductory screens, I recommend to change the following:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isShowingIntroduction, setIsShowingIntroduction] = useState(true);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef}>
      <SwiperNav />
      {isShowingIntroduction && (
        <BottomButtons
          name="Continue"
          setIsShowingIntroduction={setIsShowingIntroduction}
        />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The continue button is shown conditionally.

```
const BottomButtons = ({name, setIsShowingIntroduction}) => {
  const handleBtnNavigate = () => {
    const nextDestination = getSwipeNavigatorNextDestination(
      RootNavigation.getCurrentRouteName(),
    );
    if (nextDestination == 'ScreenNotPartOfIntroduction') {
      setIsShowingIntroduction(false);
    }
    RootNavigation.navigate(nextDestination);
  };
  return <Button title={name} onPress={() => handleBtnNavigate()} />;
};
```

What I'm doing here is creating a state variable and accompanying setter in the app component (The parent component to the continue button). This allows us to pass the setter function to the continue button. Then inside the button component we can create a check: If `nextDestination` is a screen name not part of the set of introduction screen names, you call `setIsShowingIntroduction(false)`. The app component updates and hides the button after which it navigates to `nextDestination`.

Comment: Many thanks, I was wondering if you could navigate only parts of the screen, and placing the buttons outside the stack navigation allows them to stay. Could I ask what the best way to structure the navigation container is since i only want the buttons present for the introduction screens? Should I have two Navigation containers, one with and one without buttons?